# Best approach for avoiding repeating code inside HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Submit button in my form, and when clicked, it will trigger my doPost method inside my class that extends HttpServlet.

Also, I have a variable equal to either "1", "2" or "3".
Based on what this variable is when Submit is being clicked, I want to either execute:

```
scenario 1; Code A
scenario 2; Code B
or
scenario 3; Code A + Code B
```

I can do this easily with if statements.
However, this would result in repeating code:

```
if (variable = 1) {Code A} 
else if (variable = 2) {Code B}
else {Code A + Code B}
```

What I want is Code A to only show up once, and the same goes for code B.
I tried solving this by having a specific class and method for Code A and then calling for it by creating an object etc, but it was a bad idea.

Any suggestions?

Also Code A and Code B are dependent on the same variables created in the beginning of my servlet.

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: *"but it was a bad idea"* Why? What was bad about that idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to ditch the else and simply run code a if 1 or 3 and then run code B if 2 or 3. if 1 only code A will run, if 2 only code B, if 3 both will run.

```
if (variable == 1 || variable == 3) {Code A} 
if (variable == 2 || variable == 3) {Code B}
```

Comment: ah! short circuit parameters is a very good solution. I even stopped my answer as this is the best one.

Comment: That won't even compile. Perhaps you meant to use `==`?

Comment: Correct. Fixed... Although i was going by the syntax in the question so that is a little picky...